# "ldap_modify: Server is unwilling to perform (53) additional info: shadow context; no update referral" ERROR in my ldap server

Tags: linux, openldap, replication

Iam trying to do multi master replication on my LDAP server on RHEL 7 but I am getting below error while running command:

```
#ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f ldap01.ldif

"ldap_modify: Server is unwilling to perform (53) additional info: shadow context; no update referral"  ERROR in my ldap server
```

Below are the contents of ldap01.ldif file:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcServerID
olcServerID: 1 ldap://MasterLDAP.ut.bob.com
olcServerID: 2 ldap://MasterLDAPReplica.ut.bob.com

dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
changetype:modify
add: olcSyncrepl
olcSyncrepl: rid=001
  provider=ldap://MasterLDAP.ut.bob.com
  binddn="cn=config"
  bindmethod=simple
  credentials=utkrisht
  searchbase="cn=config"
  type=refreshAndPersist
  retry="5 5 300 +"
  timeout=1
olcSyncrepl: rid=002
  provider=ldap://MasterLDAPReplica.ut.bob.com
  binddn="cn=config"
  bindmethod=simple
  credentials=utkrisht
  searchbase="cn=config"
  type=refreshAndPersist
  retry="5 5 300 +"
  timeout=1
-
add: olcMirrorMode
olcMirrorMode: TRUE
```

Comment: will anybody try to solve my problem please

Comment: It looks like there is already a `olcSyncrepl` attr in `olcDatabase={0}config`.